# Timeout while sending email on specific port with SSL enabled

Tags: vb.net, email, ssl, tls1.2, smtpclient

I get timeout error when I try to send an email using the port 465 and EnableSSL=True. If I change the port to 25 and EnableSSL=False I mail will be sent properly.

I use vb.net, domain email and password and I want to sent throught domain's SMTP.

```
Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient()
        smtpServer.Host = "ip"
        smtpServer.Port = 465 ''SSL Port
        smtpServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(FromMail,Password)
        smtpServer.EnableSsl = True
        smtpServer.Send(mail)
```

What I need to use in order to be able to send properly from Port 465 and with SSL=True?

Comment: Is port 465 open? Possibly there is more in the exception text to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: yes is open, with outlook i can send with no issues using port 465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the TLS Port instead of SSL Port. This worked for me.

Comment: could you explain?

Comment: smtpServer.Port = 465 ''SSL Port

Here instead of 465 i used the TLS Port. 465 was the SSL Port for my SMTP Client. (usually until now to the clients that i have install my program is 587, if this may help you)